# Free GeoTIFF Overlay and Tiling (i.e. Indexing) Analyser?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, performance

Has anyone come across a shareware/freeware tool for analysing the overlays and tiling (i.e the internal indexing) of GeoTIFF images?

What would be excellent would be something like a GeoTIFF tuning advisor...

Back in my Intergraph days, we had such a tool.  It allowed us to have multi-gigabyte TIFFs being displayed in maps with subsecond performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "analyse" but is [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/index.html)'s [gdal_retile](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Just a simple UI that can tell me whether overlays have been set and what the tiling settings are.  I'd like to use GDAL more, but my Python skills need some work..

Comment: try gdalinfo (http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) to give you that sort of simple overview of the GeoTiff.